# subset sum variation (?) with 2D array, negatives, and dupes

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic, divide-and-conquer

I've been smacking my head into the wall over this for days because I feel like I'm missing something big.  I have a 2D array (size n, 4) and a desired sum. The sum is reached by adding one element from each column, negative numbers and duplicates allowed.  Output is number of combos for desired sum.

The naive approach would be to get the variations of choices and add, ie:

```
for 7 rows, 4 columns
if ([0,0] + [0,1] + [0,2] + [0,3] == sum)
    matches++;
if ([0,0] + [0,1] + [0,2] + [1,3] == sum)
    matches++;
...
down to 
if ([6,0] + [6,1] + [6,2] + [6,3] == sum)
    matches++;
output matches
```

This would take N^4 time.  Not great.  What I'm struggling with is a way to reduce this (or at least a starting point) and/or divide the problem. It seems closest to the subset sum problem, but we haven't even covered dynamic programing so I don't know.

My current running idea is to treat the whole array as a single set, with them being some sort of class (K/V pair or hashtable most likely) where I can set a value to compare and a column "flag", return all subsets that match, and throw out any with duplicate columns or sets not equal to number of columns.  From what I'm reading, though, I can't tell if duplicates across columns (same column can be auto-discarded at set creation) that result in valid sums will throw me off or not, but it seems like for the most approaches yes, and that's if they can even handle negatives.

The table approach like [here](http://www.skorks.com/2011/02/algorithms-a-dropbox-challenge-and-dynamic-programming/) is just about the only thing that looks like it can be a starting point that I've seen. Am I at least on the right track, or am I way off point and making it too complicated?

Comment: Is there any practical application for that, or is it just a puzzle?

Comment: Just a problem for an algorithms class.  Seems too convoluted for any real life example and we've only covered recursion/DivCon so I'm just seeing if anyone sees a pattern I don't before attempting any dynamic programing self-teaching

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the dimensions of the problem (i.e. n < 1000)? Or is this a pure theoretical question ?

Comment: Only that the sum fits within an int, and there are 4 columns with  unlimited rows.  One test case we got has over 5000 rows which seems pretty absurd for this kind of problem

Comment: If you have only four columns, then what do the lines with five bits represent ?

Comment: I was just trying to keep it more general

Comment: You specified that we must add "one element from each column", but your example does not satisfy this assumption. Is it exactly one element per column ? Is it at least one ? Or do the ones not represent the chosen elements in the matrix ?

Comment: I was using notation starting from 0, so 0000 would be arr[0,0] + arr[0,1] + arr[0,2] + arr[0,3], 0001 =  arr[0,0] + arr[0,1] + arr[0,2] + arr[1,3], and so on.  I'll edit the post to make that more clear